# Numpy.arange: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

Here is where current_pat is defined in the code.

```
    current_idx = idx[-6:]

    current_pat = price[current_idx]

    XA = current_pat[1] - current_pat[0]
    AB = current_pat[2] - current_pat[1]
    BC = current_pat[3] - current_pat[2]
    CD = current_pat[4] - current_pat[3]

    XD = np.arange(current_pat[0],current_pat[4])
    AC = np.arange(current_pat[1],current_pat[3])

    XD_range = np.array([np.mean(XD,dtype=int) - err_allowedHAS, np.mean(XD,dtype=int) + err_allowedHAS])
    AC_range = np.array([np.mean(AC,dtype=int) - err_allowedHAS, np.mean(AC,dtype=int) + err_allowedHAS])
```

here is my error. I am honestly not sure why it has happened

```
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TradingAlgorithm\TraditionalFunctions.py", line 30, in isHeadAndShoulders
    XD = np.arange(current_pat[0],current_pat[4])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question to show what the object `current_pat` is? Or check what the result of `print(current[0], current_pat[4])` as one or both of them aren't valid inputs to `np.arange()`

Comment: I meant if you could provide code that another person can use to produce the same objects that are causing your error. The code you have doesn't help because the objects idx and price are never defined (if you try running that code you've posted it will produce an error on the first line). Being able to replicate your issue will allow use to tell you definitely what your problem is and how to fix it. At the moment the only way is to guess

Comment: What is `current_pat`?  If it is a 2d array, then `current_pat[0]` is a 1d array, which `np.arange` cannot use.  Its arguments should be simple numbers.

Answer (score 1):

From your error message I assume that one or both of the objects `current_pat[0]`/ `current_pat[4]` are not numbers. `Print(current_pat[0], current_pat[4])` to find out which of these objects are not numbers. As you've not provide code to produce the object producing your error we can't provided any more specific help to fix your problem. The documentation for [`np.arange()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) explains what arguments the function expects.

Comment: @IkennaNwagbara That's fine, what's important for debugging help is to post code that's runnable. So for instance if your object contains a list of integers write something like `import numpy as np; my_list = np.arange(10)`. Failing that write the output of `current_pat[0].shape` and `type(current_pat[0])`. There more clear your question is, the faster and better help you can expect to receive. Your error tell you that instead of passing numbers to `np.arange` you've passed an array with multiple elements, and arrays of multiple values are not valid inputs to `np.arange()`.

Comment: @IkennaNwagbara There's guidance on how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).